# format substrings of Word-Table Cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there any VBA-automateable way to format sets of characters in a Cell of a Word-Table individually.

I look for a solution to achieve the following (symbolic code)

```
Dim myLbl1 as String
Dim myTxt1 as String
Dim myLbl2 as String
Dim myTxt2 as String
Dim myLbl3 as String
Dim myTxt3 as String

….
‘ Code to fill in the afore defined Variables with random content and
' arbitrary length including linebreaks and paragraph breaks
….
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
    numrows:=3, numcolumns:=1)
oTable.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = <bold>myLbl1</bold> & vbCrLf & _
    <italic>myTxt1</italic>
oTable.Rows(2).Cells(1).Range.Text = <bold>myLbl2</bold> & vbCrLf & _
    <italic>myTxt2</italic>
oTable.Rows(3).Cells(1).Range.Text = <bold>myLbl3</bold> & vbCrLf & _
    <italic>myTxt3</italic>
Set oTable = Nothing
```

Is there any way to define a function in VBA for Word that returns a formatted string, e.g.

```
Private function setBold(txt as string) as String
  setBold = <Word-Code-to-Format-the-Provided-String-as-Bold> & txt
End function
```

What is the recommended way to achieve the goal of having substrings formatted individually, e.g.

> **myLbl3** & vbCrLf & *myTxt3*

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply anything function or HTML-like defined solution. You need to rely on document structure using objects hierarchy which, in your situation, is similar to this:

`Document > Table > Cell > Range > Paragraph > Range > Font`

and next you need to use required property.

In your situation it could be something like this (code for single cell):

```
Dim CellRange As Range
Set CellRange = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(1).Range
CellRange.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
CellRange.Paragraphs(2).Range.Font.Italic = True
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this does not solve my problem.
While I understand that word does not support HTML-style formatting, I really wonder how to solve my problem efficiently....

Comment: My problem is that I need to emphasize some words only not the whole cell.  Therefore, I tried to indicate my intention by he symbolic codes of <bold>.

Comment: what I understood from your question is that you need to bold first line and italic second line clearly indicated by line breake. For what you need try to search for `Range.Find` method to bold or italic single word (or searched text). There are a lot of examples in the internet.

Comment: Would you mind providing the respective links? Searching the web has not revealed what I was looking for.  Thanks